# Sum of polynomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How do you prove that $\large{\sum\limits_{(n_1,n_2,n_3),n_1+n_2+n_3=15,n_i\geq0,n_i\in\mathbb{Z}}}P(n_1,n_2,n_3)\times(-1)^{n_3}=(1+1-1)^{15}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  Consider the expansion of $(x+y-z)^{15}$ as per the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) and look at how the multinomial coefficients are expressed. The right choice of $(x, y, z)$ should give you the desired result.